# Not able to add plugins

Tags: wordpress, apache, linode

We have a blog setup on WordPress and our server is a linode instance which we connect through ssh.

Now when I am trying to add yoast plugin it is asking me for FTP credentials and when I am entering them still it is not connecting.

Please advise on this as we are not able to add plugins to our site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a permissions issue with your server, run the following command in your SSH terminal:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

This will grant your WordPress sites the permanent ability to add/update plugins and themes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be Permission issue. Try these simple steps:

1. 1: Open Filezilla and after entering FTP Access, connect to directory
   where your wordpress files exist.
2. Now right click on the Parent Folder of your wordpress installation and click on "Change Permission" Now enable Read/Write/Execute.
3. Now try again with Yoast Plugin. It should Work.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Let us know if it worked.